# Set focus on a `CheckboxList` control via javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a checkboxList named `cblNSGONF`. It has two list items.

Using vanilla javascript, I want to set focus to the `checkboxlist`, whether `item[0]` or `item[1]`.

I tried using `document.getElementById('cblNSGONF_0').focus()`. However, this is not working. How can I simply set focus to the control?

Answer (score 0):

Hello,

See if it's what you need:

```
document.myForm.check1.focus();
```

Sample:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1">1</br><hr>
  <input type="button" value="Move" onClick="move()">
</form>

<script>
function move() {
  document.myForm.check1.focus();
}
</script>
```

I hope it helped you!

Comment: I tried document.myForm.cblNSGONF_0.focus() and document.myForm.cblNSGONF$0.focus() and both did not work.

Comment: Make sure this is the name (myForm) of your form.
What is wrong? Can send?

Comment: yes form is form1. I used form1, but the id of the checkboxlist is cblNSGONF.  Can I use the id for the name of how to render.  Using inspect, name shows as cblNSGONF_0 or cblNSGONF$0.  Which to use/

Comment: Use the id of the option you want to place the focus on.
I believe it to be cblNSGONF_0